# Transferring bespoke CMS database to Wordpress - what do I need to consider?

Tags: php, wordpress

I've been tasked with taking a Bespoke CMS and making it into a Wordpress site. The current bespoke database for "news" is quite basic and covers only one table.

A PHP script will draw the current data, sanitize and format it ready to be INSERTed into the Wordpress database. 16000+ articles are not going to be cut and pasted!

So far I have only covered data for the `wp_posts` table - how does `wp_posts_meta` relate to `wp_posts`?

Are there any other "gotchas" I need to consider?

There is also data that could be construed as "pages", so do I just treat that in the same way?

I have previously built scripts to transfer from one bespoke to another bespoke site, and have lots of experience in Wordpress - I don't need PHP or MySQL advice, just never had to work too deeply with a WP database before and not sure how tables relate.

Comment: I'd write a script to zap the WordPress posts database and import from your original database. You can `include` the WordPress initialisation script so that the WP functions are available to you. This will allow you to run the import several times, until you are happy with it. I imagine you would do one news article = one post. The posts to posts_meta table is one:many, but since you can create posts and attach meta data using a WP function, do it the WordPress way rather than trying to insert it manually.

Comment: Thanks. That makes absolute sense as a solution and it's probably the way I'll go...

However I'm still interested about learning the relationships between Wordpress tables, so will leave this question open for now